# Google Cloud Compute engine 15% limitation

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, nlp, google-compute-engine

I am running NLP algorithms on Google Cloud but i notice that they are not quicker than my computer.

When I go on the monitor, the CPU is limited to 15%. Is there a way to reach 100%? [CPU Performance on NLP algorithm on Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKECX.png)

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons why you might not be reaching 100% CPU:

1. You have many CPU cores, but your program is only running on one. For example, if you have 6 CPU cores but are only using one, then you would be at 1/6 = %16 CPU usage. To fix this, you will have to change your program to run on all CPUs. (Note that native python doesn't support running more than one thread at once!)
2. You may be limited by something other than CPU. For example, if you are fetching data over the network, you might be limited by bandwidth or latency. Or disk throughput etc.